# Input enums at run time

Tags: c#, dynamic, parameters, enums, runtime

I have a method `GenerateOutput` which prints a list of strings. The method takes multiple enumerations as parameters and outputs a result based on which flags were entered into the method. I know enumerations are designed for compile time, but is it possible to alter the output at runtime, based on what options the user selected in the program?
Essentially, I have various check-boxes which represent the possible enumerations. When the user selects an option, that flag should be added as a parameter to the `GenerateOutput` method. Can this be done? Thanks

Comment: Please put an example/code of your GenerateOutput function

Comment: It's just test code to get this working. The method is just `void GenerateOutput(TestEnumerations tEnums)` and prints the `tEnums` value to the console. I would like to enter multiple tEnums at runtime.

Comment: Why not to enter multiple tEnums separated by e.g. comma or some other char and then parse it in your method ? like : t1,t2 and then use string.split(',') and then Enum.Parse for each one of values  ?

Comment: You mean something like void GenerateOutput(List<TestEnumerations> tEnums) ? I don't quite get it yet...

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry, I'm away from the dev machine, but I just remembered it was a bunch of console.writeline. The catch was, this method had to work without being able to modify the parameter, so I needed to use `|=` as per Jackson Pope's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to do (I'm not sure I completely understand your question) is to build up an Enum value at run-time to pass into the function.

Assuming that your enum is specified with the [flags] attribute:

```
[flags]
public enum TestEnumerations
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
    Value3 = 4,
    //etc
}
```

then you could do this:

```
// In checkbox handlers, e.g.
tEnums |= TestEnumerations.Value1;

// Where you call the method
GenerateOutput(tEnums);
```

Alternatively, as suggested by Francisco in comments, have a List list (or a HashSet if you only want each enum value to appear once):

```
// In checkbox handlers, e.g.
list.Add(TestEnumerations.Value1);

// Where you call the method
GenerateOutput(list);
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you could do `|=`. That should do it.

Comment: It'll only work if the values are powers of 2 and the [flags] attribute is set.